# Why might the CIDR/IP in DB security group be different from instance elastic IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance, which is able to connect to my RDS instance, yet its elastic IP does not appear in the DB security group of whitelisted IP's.

How might this be?

I ask because I have created a new instance, which I also want to whitelist and just entering its elastic IP does not seem like the way to do things since none of the other servers have their elastic IP listed.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There might be two causes here:

### Traffic Sources

[Security Group Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8930548/45773) do not necessarily specify IP addresses as traffic sources alone, rather regularly will refer to other security groups as well:

> The source can be an individual IP address (203.0.113.1), a range of
>   addresses (e.g., 203.0.113.0/24), **or an EC2 security group**. The
>   security group can be another group in your AWS account, a group in
>   another AWS account, or the security group itself.
>
> By specifying a security group as the source, **you allow incoming
>   traffic from all instances that belong to the source security group**.
>   [...] You might specify another security group in your account if you're creating a
>   three-tier web service (see Creating a Three-Tier Web Service).
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

Consequently, the DB security group of your [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) instance might refer to the EC2 security group used for your [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance, implying respective access rights already. See my answer to [AWS - Configuring access to EC2 instance from Beanstalk App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8930548/45773) for more details regarding this concept/approach.

### Public vs. Private IP Addresses

You might see the effect of a little known, but nonetheless important and quite helpful feature of the AWS DNS infrastructure, see section [Public and Private Addresses](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-instance-addressing) on page [Using Instance IP Addresses](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html):

> Amazon EC2 also provides an internal DNS name and a public DNS name
>   that map to the private and public IP addresses respectively. The
>   internal DNS name can only be resolved within Amazon EC2. **The public
>   DNS name resolves to the public IP address outside the Amazon EC2
>   network and the private IP address within the Amazon EC2 network**. *[emphasis mine]*

That is, it's resolving the public DNS (e.g. ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com) to the private IP address when you are using it inside the Amazon EC2 network, and to the public or elastic IP address when using it outside the Amazon EC2 network.

Accordingly, the various AWS products are usually wired up between each other by means of their private IP Addresses rather than external ones for a variety of reasons, most importantly network speed and cost (see my answer to [AWS EC2 Elastic IPs bandwidth usage and charges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10056763) for details).

Consequently, the DB security group of your Amazon RDS instance might refer to the private IP address of your Amazon EC2 instance, implying respective access rights accordingly.

Comment: After spending a very long evening and morning trying to work this out I am extremely grateful for this answer. I'll consider naming my firstborn Steffen.

Comment: For some reason, adding neither the security group nor the external ip address worked. Setting the **private ip** did the trick, however.